# Laravel src/Controllers/StatisticsController.php Path Not Found

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-7, src

I am using razek/laravel-7-visitor-tracker package.
I can't find this path which is:  src/Controllers/StatisticsController.php
Please help me to find this Controller.

Comment: It's a package file, so in the vendor folder somewhere. Here's [the source](https://github.com/Raze2/Laravel-7-Tracker/tree/master/src/Controllers)

Comment: run php artisan config:cache

Comment: run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:cache`. Any service provider you need register?